# How do I write a for loop with 2 variables in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I sorted the output from conflicting numbers that are already existing in my DB with new insert request to a file name output.
This is the output of the file.

```
    cat output
    DataBase: (9999999999)  NewDB_insert: (999-999-9999)
    DataBase: (1111111111)  NewDB_insert: (111-111-1111)
    DataBase: (2222222222)  NewDB_insert: (222-222-2222)
    DataBase: (3333333333)  NewDB_insert: (333-333-3333)
```

I want to run the same command that displays information from the same line that has the conflict. The command just pulls the DB information.

```
          showinfo -id 9999999999
          ID:9999999999
          Name: Mr.Brown
          City: New York
          Company: Acme
          Client: 1245

         showinfo -id 999-999-9999
         ID:999-999-9999
         Name: Mr.Brown
         City: New York
         Company: Acme
         Client: 1245
```

I want to use 2 variables to send the output to the screen from my file named output. So I would have the following information from my file.

```
         **From DB:**
         ID:9999999999
         Name: Mr.Brown
         City: New York
         Company: Acme
         Client: 1245

             **From NewDB_insert:**
             showinfo -id 999-999-9999
             ID:999-999-9999
             Name: Mr.Brown
             City: New York
             Company: Acme
             Client: 1245
```

So basically I would cat the file in a for loop with one variable as so.

```
for i  in `cat output | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ")("`;do echo == From DB:==;showinfo -id $i; echo ==========;done
```

Which gives me the first part of what I need. I looked online and not able to use any examples to create a for loop with 2 variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is probably: "you don't".

You're probably best off using a `while` loop with `read`.

```
sed -e 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\))[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1 \2/' output |
while read a b
do
    echo == From DB ==
    showinfo -id $a
    echo =============
    echo == From NewDB_Insert ==
    showinfo -id $b
    echo =======================
done
```

If you think there might be nasty characters, especially backslashes, in your data, you can use `read -r` and you can quote `"$a"` and `"$b"` in your `showinfo` lines.  If you're sure there won't be any such characters, you're (just about) OK with the code as written.

Note that any variables set in the `while` loop as written won't be accessible when the loop completes.  There are ways around that problem if it is, indeed, a problem.

The `sed` script looks for:

- zero or more non-open-parentheses
- an open parenthesis
- captures zero or more non-close-parentheses
- stops capturing
- a close parenthesis
- zero of more non-open-parentheses
- an open parenthesis
- captures zero of more non-close-parentheses
- stops capturing
- a close parenthesis
- zero or more other characters

and replaces them with the two captured strings (e.g. `9999999999` and `999-999-9999`) separated by a space.

Comment: Nicely done.  +1.  FWIW, another possibly simpler way of extracting the strings is `awk -F'[()]' '{print $2, $4}'`